# D3 Chord Diagram Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, visualization

Hello I am having trouble with a D3 Chord Diagram.  For some reason it works perfect in IE and Firefox but in chrome two of the connecting chords actually swap colors?

Does anyone know why this is happening? Would appreciate all the help

I also tried to get rid of the chord that is off color, and another one is off color.  Is there a reason why its off by one??

http://lkrawitz1.byethost3.com/viz/viz.html

```
//*******************************************************************
  //  CREATE MATRIX AND MAP
  //*******************************************************************
    var datas = []
d3.csv('data/data.csv', function (error, data) {
    var mpr = chordMpr(data);
datas = data;
    mpr
      .addValuesToMap('has')
      .setFilter(function (row, a, b) {
        return (row.has === a.name && row.prefers === b.name)
      })
      .setAccessor(function (recs, a, b) {
        if (!recs[0]) return 0;
        return +recs[0].count;
      });
    drawChords(mpr.getMatrix(), mpr.getMap());
  });
  //*******************************************************************
  //  DRAW THE CHORD DIAGRAM
  //*******************************************************************

function drawChords (matrix, mmap) {
    var w = 980, h = 800, r1 = h / 2, r0 = r1 - 100;
    var fill = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain([0])
        .range([""]);

    var chord = d3.layout.chord()
        .padding(.02)
        .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)
        .sortChords(d3.descending);

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(r0)
        .outerRadius(r0 + 20);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
      .append("svg:g")
        .attr("id", "circle")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

        svg.append("circle")
            .attr("r", r0 + 20);

    var rdr = chordRdr(matrix, mmap);
    chord.matrix(matrix);

 var g = svg.selectAll("g.group")
        .data(chord.groups())
      .enter().append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "group")
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mouseout", function (d) { d3.select("#tooltip").style("visibility", "hidden") });


    d3.csv('data/outer_color.csv', function (error, data) {
            g.append("svg:path")
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .style("fill", function(d,i){return data[i].color})
                .attr("d", arc);
    });

    g.append("svg:text")
        .each(function(d) { d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("font-family", "helvetica, arial, sans-serif")
        .style("font-size", "10px")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"
              + "translate(" + (r0 + 26) + ")"
              + (d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");
        })
        .text(function(d) { return rdr(d).gname; });


      var chordPaths = svg.selectAll("path.chord")
            .data(chord.chords())
            .enter().append("svg:path")
            .attr("class", "chord")
            .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(fill(d.target.index)).darker(); })
    .style("fill", function(d,i){return datas[i].color; })


            .attr("d", d3.svg.chord().radius(r0))
            .on("mouseover", function (d) {
              d3.select("#tooltip")
                .style("visibility", "visible")
                .style("top", function () { return (d3.event.pageY - 100)+"px"})
                .style("left", function () { return (d3.event.pageX - 100)+"px";})
            })
            .on("mouseout", function (d) { d3.select("#tooltip").style("visibility", "hidden") });

  function mouseover(d, i) {
        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("visibility", "hidden")
          .style("top", function () { return (d3.event.pageY - 80)+"px"})
          .style("left", function () { return (d3.event.pageX - 130)+"px";})

        chordPaths.classed("fade", function(p) {
          return p.source.index != i
              && p.target.index != i;
        });
      }
  }
```

Comment: Without code or example that is *probably* hard to debug. I'm not familiar with D3 so I can't comment knowledgeably but as a general rule more information than you have given here would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is down to order in which chord `path` elements appear in the DOM for the different browsers.

In FireFox (presumably also in IE), the chords are drawn in the DOM in the same order that they appear in raw data. The first chord path (from the Firebug) is highlighted below:

[image: chord element in FireFox]

Chrome is different: It reorders two of the chord `path` elements. The first chord path (from the Chrome Dev Tools) is highlighted here:

[image]

As you can see from the path data, these are not the same paths. I'm not sure *why* Chrome renders paths in the DOM in this different (unexpected) order! Where this impacts your example is that you use:

```
svg.selectAll("path.chord")...
```

to select each chord before assigning a color to it. The order of paths in the selection is based on order they appear in the DOM, hence why order is important. I would suggest refactoring the code to you don't need to read `data.csv` in twice (once to get data for the chord path, and then again just to assign the colors to those paths).

**Update**

One solution to this problem is to sort the `chordPaths` selection, for example on `startAngle`, before assigning colors. To do this:

```
chordPaths = svg.selectAll("path.chord");
chordPaths.sort(function(a,b) {return a.source.startAngle - b.source.startAngle }) 
chordPaths.style("fill", ...
```

See this updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xGKvEVeTLkZZLsTAiUFs?p=preview

Documentation on `selection.sort()` at: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#sort

Comment: Here's a plunker I used for debugging (although in the end didn't really need): http://plnkr.co/edit/xGKvEVeTLkZZLsTAiUFs?p=preview. The added `console.log(chordPaths.data());` prints to the console all the chords, and you can also use that to compare the order i FF vs Chrome

Comment: I changed up the code to take in your recommendations, but the problem still exists.  Is there a workaround when people view the visualization in Chrome to force those chords the color.  When I try and do that it cant event pick up that specific chord.

Comment: Is there an alt way of assigning the chord colors other than selecting all?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with d3 chord diagrams specifically, so while there should be a way of setting chord colors (perhaps in the matrix?) I've not tried it. A simple solution to your problem would be to just sort the selection (e.g by startAngle) before assigning colors. Answer updated with the code